# What is meant by "adaptive emotions" in this explanation of the TARGET model?

Tags: emotion, trauma

I was reading an article about [TARGET](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/experimentations/201710/7-steps-go-dysregulated-emotions-clear-thinking), an approach to grounding emotional disregulation (*e.g.* from trauma). It introduces a mnemonic, FREEDOM, as follows:

> 1. Focusing: Concentrating on a single idea grounded in our core values and sense of authentic self
> 2. Recognizing: Paying attention to identifying what is triggering the alarm reaction, even small things which we ordinarily wouldn’t notice
> 3. Emotions: Differentiating alarm-driven emotions from main, **adaptive** emotions
>
> ...

I think I understand alarm-driven emotions. But *everything* feels alarm-driven in that state. What are examples of adaptive emotions I might have? I'm not sure what I'm supposed to distinguish here.

I can only seem to find research papers on this topic, no infographic or guide. Probably the model is meant for psychologists to utilize, not directly for patients / the layperson. But I'm looking for grounding techniques for trauma and would like to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [the publication](https://qic-ag.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Trauma-Affect-Regulation-Guide-for-Education-and-Therapy-TARGET-Intervention-April-201510-41715.pdf) the article was referring to. In the paper they are referred to as "main" emotions.

> The goal of this skill is to identify two types of emotions. The first are "alarm" or reactive emotions such as terror, rage, and guilt. A second type of emotion, "main" emotions, include positive feelings and feelings that represent positive strivings. By balancing both kinds of emotions a person can reflect and draw on his/her own values and hopes even when the alarm is activated.

It's more salient to me to relabel them **reactive** versus **goal-driven** emotions. (Maybe even **"intentional"** emotions.)